# Full Join on Group

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, full-outer-join

I'm facing a logic issue with my Query.

I have two tables **`Table1`** and **`Table2`**, where `Table1` consists of:

- `value` *to be summed*
- `Id`    *to be grouped by*
- `Code`  *holds foreign-key to `Table2`*

And `Table2` consists of

- `Code`
- `Des` *the text description of code*

What I'm trying to do is, group by `Table1.Id`, full join on `Table2.Code`, but, for each resulting group, I want to show all the rows from Table2 for each group generated by the query.

**Sample code:**

```
SELECT
    Table2.Code, Table1.Id, Table2.DES, 
    SUM(Table1.Value) AS SUM_VAL
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'A' AS Code, 1 AS Id, 10 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS Code, 2 AS Id, 20 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Code, 1 AS Id, 10 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Code, 1 AS Id, 30 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Code, 2 AS Id, 50 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'C' AS Code, 1 AS Id, 40 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'C' AS Code, 2 AS Id, 60 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'D' AS Code, 1 AS Id, 20 AS Value FROM DUAL

) Table1
FULL JOIN
(
    SELECT 'A' AS Code, 'This is A' AS DES FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Code, 'This is B' AS DES FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'C' AS Code, 'This is C' AS DES FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'D' AS Code, 'This is D' AS DES FROM DUAL
) Table2
ON Table1.Code = Table2.Code
GROUP BY
    Table2.Code, Table1.Id, Table2.DES
ORDER BY
    Table2.Code, Table1.Id ASC
```

**Result:**

```
A   1   This is A   10
A   2   This is A   20
B   1   This is B   40
B   2   This is B   50
C   1   This is C   40
C   2   This is C   60
D   1   This is D   20
```

**Required Result:**

```
A   1   This is A   10
A   2   This is A   20
B   1   This is B   40
B   2   This is B   50
C   1   This is C   40
C   2   This is C   60
D   1   This is D   20
D   2   This is D   0    <- This is the target
```

Comment: coalesce(Table1.Code, Table2.Code) in select and group by?

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: Improved full outer join result, when no hit in table1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have somehow to show the value pair `(D,2)` eg. by making a code list with possible values and translating `NULL` to `0`:

```
  SELECT code.code,
         code.id,
         des.des,
         NVL (SUM (val.value), 0) sum_val
    FROM (SELECT 'A' code, 1 id FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT 'A', 2 FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT 'B', 1 FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT 'B', 2 FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT 'C', 1 FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT 'C', 2 FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT 'D', 1 FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT 'D', 2 FROM DUAL) code
         INNER JOIN (SELECT 'A' code, 'This is A' des FROM DUAL
                     UNION
                     SELECT 'B', 'This is B' FROM DUAL
                     UNION
                     SELECT 'C', 'This is C' FROM DUAL
                     UNION
                     SELECT 'D', 'This is D' FROM DUAL) des
            ON code.code = des.code
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 'A' code, 1 id, 10 VALUE FROM DUAL
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'A', 2, 20 FROM DUAL
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'B', 1, 10 FROM DUAL
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'B', 1, 30 FROM DUAL
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'B', 2, 50 FROM DUAL
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'C', 1, 40 FROM DUAL
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'C', 2, 60 FROM DUAL
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'D', 1, 20 FROM DUAL) val
            ON code.code = val.code AND code.id = val.id
GROUP BY code.code, code.id, des.des
ORDER BY code, id
```

`UNION ALL` is used in `val` because duplicates can occur.

No need for `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Although your suggested solution changed the entire structure of the query, _which is not possible in my original code, the above code is just a sample to mimic the case I'm facing, and much more complicated code_, but you gave me the hint to how to solve the issue, thank you. I will update the question within a few minutes.

Comment: In the full join statement (original code):  
I selected  1 and 2 and joined them with **A**, **B**, **C**, and **D** to give me all the possibilities of **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** with **1** and **2**, so that `Table2` now contains `Code`, `Text` and `Id`
  and then on the `join filter` between `Table1` and `Table2`, I've added the `and Table1.id = table2.id` also to the condition
  This solved the problem

Comment: If only the codes 1 and 2 will ever be relevant, it sounds reasonable. Otherwise you can consider the dynamic approach sugested by Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the combinations of id and value, then use `cross join` to get the rows and a `left join` to bring in the rest of the values:

```
select t2.code, i.value, t2.desc, coalesce(cnt, 0) as cnt
from (select distinct id from table1) i cross join
     table2 t2 left join
     (select id, value, count(*) as cnt
      from table1
      group by id, value
     ) iv
     on iv.id = i.id and iv.code = t2.code
```

This should be much simpler than listing out all the combinations manually.

Comment: Thanks, I've tackled it in a similar way, check my comment in Jon Tofte-Hansen answer

Comment: @simsim . . . The key to this solution is to generate all the *rows* you want with a `cross join` and then to add the appropriate columns using `left join`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Table2.Code, Table2.NAT, Table2.DES, 
    SUM(Table1.Value) AS SUM_VAL
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'A' AS Code, 'QA' AS Id, 10 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS Code, 'NQA' AS Id, 20 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Code, 'QA' AS Id, 10 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Code, 'QA' AS Id, 30 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Code, 'NQA' AS Id, 50 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'C' AS Code, 'QA' AS Id, 40 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'C' AS Code, 'NQA' AS Id, 60 AS Value FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'D' AS Code, 'QA' AS Id, 20 AS Value FROM DUAL

) Table1
FULL JOIN
(
    SELECT 'QA' NAT,'A' AS Code, 'This is A' AS DES FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'QA' NAT,'B' AS Code, 'This is B' AS DES FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'QA' NAT,'C' AS Code, 'This is C' AS DES FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'QA' NAT,'D' AS Code, 'This is D' AS DES FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT 'NQA' NAT,'A' AS Code, 'This is A' AS DES FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'NQA' NAT,'B' AS Code, 'This is B' AS DES FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'NQA' NAT,'C' AS Code, 'This is C' AS DES FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'NQA' NAT,'D' AS Code, 'This is D' AS DES FROM DUAL
) Table2
on TABLE2.NAT = TABLE1.ID
      AND Table2.Code= Table1.Code
GROUP BY
    Table2.Code, Table2.NAT, Table2.DES
ORDER BY
    Table2.Code, Table2.NAT ASC
```