# MySQL is losing rows on a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, and I'm trying to join them together in a specific way. The results I'm looking for would be:

```
site statusname total
2   Follow-Up   0
2   Off Study   0
2   Screening   1
2   Treatment   0
1   Follow-Up   0
1   Off Study   0
1   Screening   2
1   Treatment   0
```

However, this is what's being returned:

```
site statusname total
1   Follow-Up   0
1   Off Study   0
1   Screening   2
2   Screening   1
1   Treatment   0
```

My actual query (the one that returns the wrong results) looks like:

```
SELECT
    sitestatus.site                                 AS site,
    sitestatus.statusname                           AS statusname,
    count(participant.id)                           AS total
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        participant.`site`                          AS site,
        participant_status.`name`                   AS statusname,
        participant_status.`id`                     AS status
    FROM
        participant_status
    CROSS JOIN
        participant) AS sitestatus
LEFT JOIN
    participant
ON
    participant.`site` = sitestatus.`site`          AND
    participant.`status` = sitestatus.`status`
GROUP BY
    sitestatus.`statusname`,
    participant.`site`
```

However, if I make a slight (but unacceptable) modification, adding a `WHERE` clause to the subselect and using a `UNION`, I get my desired results. Here's the query:

```
SELECT
    sitestatus.site                                 AS site,
    sitestatus.statusname                           AS statusname,
    count(participant.id)                           AS total
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        participant.`site`                          AS site,
        participant_status.`name`                   AS statusname,
        participant_status.`id`                     AS status
    FROM
        participant_status
    CROSS JOIN
        participant
    WHERE site=1) AS sitestatus
LEFT JOIN
    participant
ON
    participant.`site` = sitestatus.`site`          AND
    participant.`status` = sitestatus.`status`
GROUP BY
    sitestatus.`statusname`,
    participant.`site`

UNION

SELECT
    sitestatus.site                                 AS site,
    sitestatus.statusname                           AS statusname,
    count(participant.id)                           AS total
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        participant.`site`                          AS site,
        participant_status.`name`                   AS statusname,
        participant_status.`id`                     AS status
    FROM
        participant_status
    CROSS JOIN
        participant
    WHERE site=2) AS sitestatus
LEFT JOIN
    participant
ON
    participant.`site` = sitestatus.`site`          AND
    participant.`status` = sitestatus.`status`
GROUP BY
    sitestatus.`statusname`,
    participant.`site`;
```

I cannot figure out where my missing rows are going.

Here are the relevant schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `participant` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `participant_status` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

(EDIT: Now using `CROSS JOIN` as suggested by Tim.)

Comment: use union all operator between two query .

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752391/full-join-on-group), it might help you, it is in Oracle, but it addresses the same logic

Comment: possibly you must be getting null rows right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Tim, I was able to arrive at an answer:

```
SELECT t2.site, t2.statusname AS statusname, COALESCE(t1.total,0) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT site, status, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM participant
    GROUP BY site, status
) AS t1
RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT participant_status.id AS status, participant_status.name AS statusname, participant.site FROM participant
    CROSS JOIN
    participant_status
    ORDER BY status, site
) AS t2
ON  t1.site = t2.site AND t1.status = t2.status
```

Comment: Style points: Usually, it's better to make the `FROM` reference _always_ have a row, and subsequent references _maybe_ have a row (IOW, switch your two subqueries, and make it a `LEFT JOIN`).  It's also usually better to put `ORDER BY` at the outermost level - I'm not sure how guaranteed ordering is after a join

Answer (score 4):

The `UNION` operator has a default behavior of removing duplicate records which occur in both result sets which are being aggregated.  If you want to retain all records from both of your queries, you should use the `UNION ALL` operator:

```
query1
UNION ALL
query2
```

Here is my attempt at what a correct approach to this query might be:

```
SELECT t2.site, t2.name AS statusname, t1.total
FROM
(
    SELECT site, status, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM participant
    GROUP BY site, status
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    (SELECT DISTINCT site FROM participant)
    CROSS JOIN
    participant_status
) t2
ON t1.site = t2.site AND t1.status = t2.id
```

Comment: I don't want my query to have _any_ `UNION` operator. What I hoped to show with the `UNION` example, was that I expected more data to return in the original query.

Comment: hi @tim ... i'm not sure i understand. in the query that isn't working correctly, i don't have a `WHERE` clause. in the extra-long query that does work (as long as there are only two sites), i do have a `WHERE` clause, but i don't want to use that query. the purpose of the long query (with the `WHERE` and `UNION`) is to show that i think the inner query is returning everything i want, but the outer query or the `LEFT JOIN` is throwing data away

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say don't do a join by saying `FROM table1, table2` because it isn't clear what the join column is.  To get the answer you really  want someone (or something) is going to have to rewrite the query.  Your current structure makes it that much more difficult.

Comment: ah yes, i understand what you're saying. thanks for highlighting that. so i'm probably going about this the wrong way, but i don't actually want a join column. i want to generate the cross-product of site = (1,2) and status = (1,2,3,4) ... to get 8 rows like (1, 1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2,3), (2,4). (btw i know you don't have to help me with this, but i truly appreciate it)

Comment: Maybe I can help.  This sounds like you want to do a `CROSS JOIN` to get the cross product of the 2 sets.

Comment: i've updated by query to do the `CROSS JOIN` but the results haven't changed. the inner query still returns all 8 rows, but the outer query causes 3 of them disappear

Comment: Forgive me, but could I also request that you show sample input tables as well?  A picture is worth a thousand words on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100685/discussion-between-alan-c-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: @AlanC. Please let me know whether or not this query worked for you.

Comment: you did it. i had to make a couple of tweaks (that took me about 5 minutes), but your work paved the way.